# Spring Boot - REST API to Post file and return Zipped file in response

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, zip, http-post

Im trying to receive a file from an HTTP POST which I split into individual files wand then need to return that in a zip file.  I am trying to return the file and I have tried everything to return the file, but I am unable to recieve the file... any thoughts?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/splitFile", headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"), produces ="application/zip", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void SplitFile(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile[] file, HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException {



    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        File uplFile = new File(file[i].getOriginalFilename());
        uplFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(uplFile);
        fos.write(file[i].getBytes());
        fos.close();

        System.out.println("Splitting File: " + uplFile.getName());
        uploadHelper Help = new uploadHelper();

        ArrayList<String> filestrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        filestrings = uplHelp.GetSplitFiles(uplFile);


        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int filenumber = 0;
        for (String filedata : filestrings) {
            filenumber = filenumber + 1;
            sb.append(filedata);
            ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry("file_" + filenumber + ".data");
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(e);

            byte[] data = sb.toString().getBytes();
            zipOutputStream.write(data, 0, data.length);
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();


        }
        System.out.println("Splitting File - Split " + filestrings.size() + " files");

        if (zipOutputStream != null) {
            zipOutputStream.finish();
            zipOutputStream.flush();
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(zipOutputStream);
        }
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedOutputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.zip");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("gzip");
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();


    }
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
    response.flushBuffer();


}
```

Comment: Why do you use `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);`?

Comment: Sorry typo updated